# Find repeating patterns in string

Tags: arrays, pattern-matching

In today's AdventOfCode question users were tasked to find repeating patterns in a string, and output that.

For example, my string was:

```
R8L10L12R4R8L12R4R4R8L10L12R4R8L10R8R8L10L12R4R8L12R4R4R8L10R8R8L12R4R4R8L10R8R8L12R4R4
```

This consists of 3 repeating patterns:

```
A = R8L10L12R4
B = R8L12R4R4
C = R8L10R8
```

which means my string could be encoded to `ABACABCBCB`

How would I do this by algorithm? I did this by hand, and all solutions of other people I looked at were also done by hand. What is the programatic way to solve this?

Edit:

Information we had:

- maximum of 3 patterns
- `R8L10L12R4` would be transformed to `R,8,L,10,L,12,R,4`. The transformed pattern could not be longer than 20 characters

Comment: grab every substring of your string which is 20 chars long. search if there are 2 occurences of this substring in your string. if yes, it's a pattern. now do this for every 19 char substring, then 18 char and so on. repeat until you find 3 patterns.

Comment: Okay, I did it this way now, but this felt like applying some sort of compression algorithm or some tree thing or something I wasn't aware of when solving the problem.

Comment: This is just the first thing that came to my mind. If there is a super elegant solution please let me know :)

Comment: I also found this: https://i.redd.it/9we2yytiu5541.jpg